# How to connect NSPopUpButton with measurement unit choices to the way a NSTextField is presented?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings, nsnumberformatter, nsvaluetransformer

In a Core Data entity i have a „length" attribute. I save the length in centimeters.

I want to give the user the possibility to view and edit the length in centimeters or inches. So i place a NSTextField next to a NSPopUpButton with cm and inch as choices.

What is the best way to format the NSTextField according to the choice taken by the NSPopUpButton? If reasonable for this problem i would want to work with bindings as much as possible.

I saw there are

- NSNumberFormatters and
- NSValueTransformers

or i could write custom code to transform the units?

What is the most elegant way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you persist the cm/in choice for the user as a per-entity choice with an attribute on the entity, you could do it with a value binding and a custom value transformer with reverse transformation on the textfield, a cm/in choice binding on the popup, and a keyPathsForValuesAffectingLength class method on the entity.

If the attribute displaysInInches-- or whatever you call it-- is registered as a keyPath that affects length's value, the custom value transformer would get called when the popup is toggled, and the text field would update.

If the cm/in choice is from user defaults (if the change is not per-instance), you could bind the popup to user defaults and have the custom value transformer take the default into consideration, but changing that popup wouldn't refresh the textfield.  So I think you'd need an IBAction just to touch the instance's length.

You could add a number formatter on top of that-- especially if your value transformer transforms into NSNumber and not NSString-- but mostly for localization and number of significant digits, not for the cm/in math.

Comment: Thank you. I will experiment with your ideas. There are no defaults involved and i do not want to store the per-entity choice. In my usecase the user might want to see/enter the length one time as inch, one time as cm, based on how the real-world data is presented to her/him.

Comment: If the popup state is view-only, the value transform is going to have to be view-only as well.  So perhaps that does launch you towards a custom `NSFormatter`, but I've heard little of such things.   My "answer" is more of a long comment, so please answer yourself if that works out!

Comment: I made a custom `CmToInchValueTransformer` and have already successfully tested it, when i assign it to a `NSTextField` durable. Now what’s missing is the way i can connect it, so that it get’s used, when _inch_ is selected in the `NSPopUpButton` and does not get used when _cm_ is selected.

Comment: The transformer needs to have access to the popup button's state through an outlet.  And the popup needs to trigger a reevaluation when its state changes through an action.   This is because the button state is stored only in the view and not in the model.